# Python | How to append data to csv file with new line

Tags: python, csv

I have this dataset here:

```python
import csv

numbers = [111, 222, 333, 444]
```

And I want to be able to output the contents to a csv file like so with no header:

```python
111
222
333
444
```

I've tried this:

```python
with open('numbers.csv', 'a') as nums:
    writer = csv.writer(nums, lineterminator='\n')

    writer.writerow(numbers)
```

Output:

```python
111,222,333,444
```

I know it's because I'm using writerow(), but I have no clue how to write to the csv file without making it so. I've tried nums.write() but again, no clue how to space new lines

Comment: You don't need `csv`, actually. `print(*numbers, file=nums)` will do the job. Check docs of [`print()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) for additional info. Alternatively you can use `nums.write("\n".join(str(n) for n in numbers))` or `nums.write("\n".join(map(str, numbers)))`.

Comment: Your expected output shows *one number per row*. But your code is outputting *one row* with all the numbers. Instead of  `writer.writerow(numbers)` do `for n in numbers: writer.writerow([n])`.

Comment: Thank you, I'll use this one, as it's cleaner. Do you mind putting this as a response so I can mark it as the answer? Also thank you @OlvinRoght for your answer as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

writer.writerow actually takes a list as an argument and interpretes it like a CSV row. So I suppose you are trying to create a new row for each element in your list.
This is a way to do that:

```py
import csv

numbers = [111, 222, 333, 444]

with open('numbers.csv', 'a') as nums:
    writer = csv.writer(nums, lineterminator='\n')

    for i in numbers:                     # iterate through your list
        writer.writerow([i])              # write a row containing each element
```